# Why isn't hashmap insertion `O(1)` worst-case when separate chaining is used?

Tags: arrays, hash, linked-list, hashmap, hash-collision

I have learned how a hashmap is implemented: an array of linked lists, if *separate chaining* is used. I know that when a key-value pair `(key, val)` is inserted, the hashmap inserts the pair `{key, val}` in the linked list at entry `hash(key) % array.size` in the underlying array.

[image]

So, for the insertion process, all that is done is

- A computation of the hash function; also,
- A modulo operation (take the hash modulo the array size); also,
- An array access; finally,
- Allocating a linked list node and inserting it into the linked list.

However, isn't this insertion process `O(1)`, assuming the hash is `O(1)`, because everything is then `O(1)` except possibly the linked list insertion, and for the linked list insertion, couldn't we always choose to insert the pair at the *beginning* of the linked list, which is `O(1)`? Isn't this `O(1)` always? If so, then why don't hash tables use this strategy?

Comment: And while something like an `std::unordered_multimap` in C++ never has to do this check, there is *still* the risk of having to re-hash on insertion as the capacity of the hash map is exceeded. If you've never re-hashed, inserts could be strictly `O(1)`  but only while loosing average case `O(1)` for lookups in return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't want duplicate keys in any sort of map, ie when you try to insert a pair `(key, value)` you need to check whether that `key` already exists in the map or not. For this check you have to

1. Find the respective bucket via `hash(key)`
2. Check if `key` already exists in that bucket

And for checking if the key already exists, you have to iterate the bucket, which can have `n` elements. Thus, with buckets impelemented as linked list, the worst-case for insert is still *O(n)*

There are other implementations, that implement the buckets as balanced trees. With that implementation you can lower the worst-case for insert to *O(log n)*

Answer (score 1):

For a map where the key is required to be *unique* (e.g. `std::unordered_map` in C++), traversal of the list is still `O(1)` in the *average* case, but the key needs to be searched for first in the bucket. This lookup is never constant time.

---

Even for a map where the key is *not* required to be unique (e.g. `std::unordered_multimap` in C++), while the insertion *could* be done strictly in `O(1)` by always prepending to each bucket, there is *often* a requirement that clashes with that, and that is the support for "equal ranges" which still require sorting stuff into the bucket.

So the need for an efficient lookup by key renders the fastest possible insertion method still sub-par for multi-maps too.

---

Realistically, the only container  which *can* skip all these checks is if the key is guaranteed to be unique by design, but *no* such check has to be performed at runtime. Only then you can get `O(1)` inserts without any pitfalls.

---

The remaining issue is, you expect not only average `O(1)` inserts, but also reads. And for that many hashmaps support dynamic resizing of the hash table, which involves a re-hashing of all already inserted elements in order to get down to reasonable bucket sizes again.

Which then gets you that true `O(size())` complexity on inserts most implementations have.

Only hash-maps with a static table size can avoid this.